# Adding all features of a DataFrame to a new DataFrame if one feature meets condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to write all features (columns) of an index in a Pandas DataFrame into a new DataFrame if one of the features meets a certain criteria. Specificially, if the value for the `'Distance_Between'` column in `EQdataW` is less than 1000 I want all data in that row/index written into the new, `'viableData'` DataFrame. Preferably I want all the features in the row of this DataFrame and another to be appended to viableData. However, I am trying it with just one first.

Here is what I currently have written:

```
viableData = [] 
for i in range(len(EQdataW)): 
    if [EQdataW['Distance_Between'] <= 1000] == True: 
        viableData = viableData.append(EQdataW[i,:])
    else: 
        print('Index:', i, 'Distance > 1,000 km')
```

It is simply returning: `Index: 0 Distance > 1,000 km` and onward for the rest of the indexes. To me this is pointing towards the `if` statement, but I cannot figure out how to write it differently to resolve this bug. How can I change my code to get all features of the `EQdataW` DataFrame into the `viableData` DataFrame when the value for that index in the `'Distance_Between'` column is less than 1000?

Comment: Generally you don't need to or want to use loops in pandas.  Can you give me an example of the dataframes you have and what you expect it to look like after? I can't quite wrap my head around it so far.  You can use df.loc to find if a value is in a certain column/feature without looping, but I need to know what you expect to append to give a good answer. `df.loc[(df['Feature'] <= 1000)]` for example, will return all the rows that this feature is less than or equal to 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by abandoning the `if` statement attempt and by instead using Pandas as it is intended to be used. The above code was replaced by the following:

```
viableEQData = EQdataW[EQdataW['Distance_Between'] <= 1000]
viableVCData = VCdataW[VCdataW['Distance_Between'] <= 1000]

# Merge VC & EQ based on the 'Distance_Between'
combinedData = pd.merge(viableEQData, viableVCData, how='outer', on='Distance_Between')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a DataFrame `EQdataW`  with column `Distance_Between` and others.

To filter only the rows which have `Distance_Between` < 1000, you can use [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

```py
import pandas as pd

# Given a DataFrame with col Distance_Between and others I'm calling a and b
EQdataW = pd.DataFrame({'Distance_Between': [900, 1000, 1200, 800], 'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

# Filter the data with .loc
viableData = EQdataW.loc[EQdataW['Distance_Between'] < 1000]
```

`viableData` will be a DataFrame with rows 0 and 3:

```
 Distance_Between   a   b
0             900   1   5
3             800   4   8
```

---

If you need to append data from another DataFrame with the same columns, you can use [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
# Another DataFrame with the same columns
anotherDataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'Distance_Between': [500, 400], 'a': [1, 2], 'b': [5, 6]})

# Append DataFrames
viableData = pd.concat([viableData, anotherDataFrame])
```

`viableData` will be:

```
 Distance_Between   a   b
0             900   1   5
3             800   4   8
0             500   1   5
1             400   2   6
```